# On ELU and Meta.ELU, filter buttons not aligned in user page

Tags: bug, design

I am using Google Chrome version 25.0.1364, on Windows 7. For me, in the "Users" section of both EL&U and the Meta site, the last filter button of each set is aligned a bit too high. For example, on the [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation) page:

[image]

Similar misalignment is also present on the other pages, like "new users" and "voters". This shows up on Meta.ELU, too:

[image]

I checked StackOverflow and MSO, but they seem to be fine. Can this issue please be fixed?

Comment: Repro (same specs)

Comment: This started happening about a week ago. I keep wanting to check it at work, and forgetting. My setup at home is Chrome/Vista. Looks fine in Opera, FF, IE, and even Safari. Reminds me of a [similar bug a while back](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3160/the-faq-link-on-main-no-longer-fits-in-chrome), where Chrome was the culprit as well, and fixed itself after a couple weeks.

Comment: I can reproduce it on Mac OS X 10.8.2. as well.